# XCode 4.3, "Cannot define category for undefined class" using multiple headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3

Up until recently, I had a project compiling fine in XCode; however now I am scratching my head with the following:

> Cannot define category for undefined class 'myClass'

I have a header that extends another through a category, like such:

myClass.h

```
@interface myClass:UIView<...>
@property ....
-(void) method....
@end
```

myClass+myCategory.h

```
#import "myClass.h"
@interface myClass (MyCategory)
-(void) method2...
@end
```

myClass.m

```
#import "myClass.h"
#import "myClass+myCategory.h"
...
```

My understanding from searching, as well as from the history of this project compiling and running is that this should be valid Objective-C, which leads me to XCode. Any ideas here?

Comment: this is not an XCode question. Where does the error show up?

Comment: During compilation. It seems like the preprocessor is not finding the myClass.h interface. However, they are all within the same XCode project.

Comment: did you try to clean the project?

Comment: Yes, both the project and the build folder.

Comment: What are you doing here ?  Writing a category for UIView ?  If so this seems to be not proper way of defining categories?

Comment: @nkongara. He's defining a `UIView` subclass and creating a category over it. It looks legit to me. @Sparky have you tried to replicate the same situation in a fresh project?

Comment: @Gabriele I have and it does work, which is why I am really stumped.

Comment: @Nkongara, I am trying to create a separate category. This has worked in the past. This is ending up as a library, and the point is to separate public headers (visible API selectors) from private headers (internal stuff).

Comment: try cleaning the derivate data of the project from the organizer. This actually seems like an XCode problem, I was mistaken.

Comment: That was actually a really good idea; unfortunately it's still not cooperating. I have checked all the project settings and all files are included, both headers are set to be copied. I am pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: is there the chance that the class is not included in the target?

Comment: oh no sorry, you already told you checked it. I'm running out of ideas too...

Comment: I assume it is a project issue but I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I think it must be an issue with the .m somehow. I noticed if I remove the category declaration on myClass+myCategory.h then XCode complains about duplicate interface definition. So obviously it is aware of the conflicting .h files. Why can't it find the class, then?

Comment: That's strange to see class extension being imported to the class implementation, as we can't see all the imports I'd assume that you have imports loop.

Comment: Sometimes you have "My" and sometimes "my", are you sure they all match in the right places?  I'm assuming you didn't post the actual code since it has ... in it and won't compile.

Comment: The cases do properly match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your compiler is running into the category header before it's seen the file that the category is defined or referenced in.

D Carney was on to something when he said that adding the import to the precompiled header would help, but he's mistaken in what to import. You want to ensure that your compiler sees your base class header before the category so it knows what class the category applies to.

Comment: Changing my accepted answer to this one, as Moshe seems to have an actual theory, rather than my "who knows" answer.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to see. Thanks. I'm surprised this question and answer haven't gotten more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no explanation for the above issue. I created a new project and re-added all my source files to it. Compiles now without any issue.

Comment: XCode and his mysteries. Amen.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Turns out that you need to add the category include to your `...-Prefix.pch` file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
    #import "myClass+myCategory.h"
#endif
```